# Keyboard shortcut to switch between Songs, Albums, Artists, Genres, Videos, Playlists in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

I wasn’t able to find keyboard shortcuts for switching between Songs, Albums, Artists, Genres, Videos, Playlists in iTunes. This is the only thing that is missing in order to have a complete keyboard experience.

Are there any shortcuts for this? And if not, can they be created and how?

Answer (score 2):

You could [assign shortcuts to scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "iTunes"
    if exists radio button 4 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1 then
        click radio button 4 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1
    else -- if the sidebar is not shown
        click radio button 4 of radio group 1
    end if
end tell
```

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set view of browser window 1 to user playlist "Music"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "iTunes"
    if exists radio button 4 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1 then
        click radio button 4 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1
    else
        click radio button 4 of radio group 1
    end if
end tell
```

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set view of browser window 1 to (get user playlist 1 where special kind is none)
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks.

The first two scripts output the following error, when executed in iTunes:

Error Number:System Events got an error: Can’t get radio group 1 of window 1 of process "iTunes". Invalid index.
-1719

The 3rd one is working as specified.

Do you have any idea how to make the others work?

Comment: They didn't work when the sidebar was shown, but I edited the answer.

Comment: I tried it again, with the sidebar turned on and off, but it turned out the same:  
Error Number:System Events got an error: Can’t get radio group 1 of window 1 of process "iTunes". Invalid index.
-1719  
(iTunes version 11.0.4.)

Comment: If it was the first script, it's just meant to click the fourth tab in the bar at the top. It doesn't work if the bar at the top doesn't exist.

Comment: The tabs are present all the time 100%. Just in case we talk about different group of tabs I posted a [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/10cf06f8-3d26-4918-852d-2d38ea4062a6/2d356ecdd1442a04b6418bf80e18a8c8).  I tried the 1st and 2nd script, sidebar on and off, but to no avail. The 3rd one is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

The following keyboard shortcuts work in the Music app (vers. 1.2.5.7)

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> switches to **Recently Added**
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> switches to **Artists**
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> switches to **Albums**
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> switches to **Songs**